# How to maintain session persistence with desktop application as client

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

a CF9 application has to be integrated with a desktop application. All request/response cycles are in XML. The first request from desktop appliction to CF is to login with a userid. How I can maintain sessions as cookies are not allowed. This desktop application in integration with another site (on php platform) uses a sessionID.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Testxml Status="Login" Type="Request" Error_Message="">
  <login>
   <userCode>020172</userCode>
   <pwCode />
  </login>
</Testxml>
```

It gets a response from server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Testxml  Status="Login" Type="Response"  Session_ID="7648224" >
</Testxml>
```

Now, this sessionID is carried over in each subsequent request as an attribute in the root node. Can I do something like this on CF side? Modifying the code for this desktop application is not the option I have.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Which side is making the request (ColdFusion server or desktop app) and which side is maintaining the session? Are you rewriting the desktop application in ColdFusion?

Comment: Does each and every request from the client has some sort of unique identifier? OR heaven forbid, are the IP addresses fixed?

Comment: @Miguel-F, sorry for the confusion. It is 2 way traffic. But it is desktop which will make Request and CF side will provide Response. This request-response cycle will start with first login request from desktop application. CF has to generate a sessionid and has to be sent back as response.

Comment: @JamesAMohler, the answer is "No" to both of your questions

Comment: What kind of a request is it doing? You are saying CF9, so it is not REST is it?

Comment: Have you tried setting `this.setClientCookies = false`?